# Spring internationalization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, internationalization, interceptor

Iam working on a small project, when i try to implement i18n in spring,it not working,even when i try to change default language its not working. here is my spring-servlet.xml code

```
            <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" /> 
   <!--  <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></property>
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>-->
</bean> 

          <mvc:interceptors>
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

i have 4 messages.properties in classpath messages.properties,messages_en.properties,messages_fr.properties,messages_de.properties
the default language not changing always its using messages_en.properties if remove messages_en.properties file ,then its using messages.properties.

And my hyperlinks are not working in jsp file

```
         Language : <a href="?lang=en">English</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="?lang=fr">French</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="?lang=de">german</a>
```

when i use ${locale} in jsp it prints nothing..
plz help me tia..

Answer (score 0):

Try ${requestContext.locale} instead of ${locale}.

And maybe jsp you test, has already '?' character in path, so  lands on page with 2x'?' ?